# E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands c++

Tags: c++

```
void snakeorladder(int myplace)
{
    char L1Top = 0, L1Bot = 0, L2Top = 0, L2Bot = 0, L3Top = 0, L3Bot = 0, S1Top = 0, S1Bot = 0, S2Top = 0, S2Bot = 0, S3Top = 0, S3Bot = 0;

    if (L1Top == myplace)
        cout << "L1Top";
    if (L1Bot == myplace)
        cout << "L1Bot";
    if (L2Top == myplace)
        cout << "L2Top";
    if (L2Bot == myplace)
        cout << "L2Bot";
    if (L3Top == myplace)
        cout << "L3Top";
    if (L3Bot == myplace)
        cout << "L3Bot";
    if (S1Top == myplace)
        cout << "S1Top";
    if (S1Bot == myplace)
        cout << "S1Bot";
    if (S2Top == myplace)
        cout << "S2Top";
    if (S2Bot == myplace)
        cout << "S2Bot";
    if (S3Top == myplace)
        cout << "S3Top";
    if (S3Bot == myplace)
        cout << "S3Bot";
};

int main()
{
    cout <<  snakeorladder(place25);  // <--- Error on this line
}
```

This is the error I am getting at the indicated line (at the end of the example code)

> E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands

Can someone provide some assistance, please?

Comment: Your function returns nothing, (`void`), so what do you expect should be printed to the console?? Also doesn't the function itself already print out what you want?

Comment: What is the **full** error message? The full error message should state what the types of your operands are. Once you have that information, you are much closer to knowing why that operator fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the *return value* of `snakeorladder()` to `cout << ...`, but `snakeorladder()` has a `void` return value - ie, it doesn't return anything at all.  So there is nothing to pass to `operator<<`.

Simply get rid of the print statement in `main()`, especially since `snakeorladder()` already prints everything internally:

```cpp
int main()
{
    snakeorladder(place25);
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to change `snakeorladder()` to return something that `main()` can actually print, eg:

```cpp
const char* snakeorladder(int myplace)
{
    char L1Top = 0, L1Bot = 0, L2Top = 0, L2Bot = 0, L3Top = 0, L3Bot = 0, S1Top = 0, S1Bot = 0, S2Top = 0, S2Bot = 0, S3Top = 0, S3Bot = 0;

    if (L1Top == myplace)
        return "L1Top";
    if (L1Bot == myplace)
        return "L1Bot";
    if (L2Top == myplace)
        return "L2Top";
    if (L2Bot == myplace)
        return "L2Bot";
    if (L3Top == myplace)
        return "L3Top";
    if (L3Bot == myplace)
        return "L3Bot";
    if (S1Top == myplace)
        return "S1Top";
    if (S1Bot == myplace)
        return "S1Bot";
    if (S2Top == myplace)
        return "S2Top";
    if (S2Bot == myplace)
        return "S2Bot";
    if (S3Top == myplace)
        return "S3Top";
    if (S3Bot == myplace)
        return "S3Bot";
    return "";
};

int main()
{
    cout << snakeorladder(place25);
}
```